# How to mount external HDD with fat32 owner rights

Tags: external-hdd, fat32, permissions

When my external HDD mounts, it get mounted with root as owner. So I can only look read files. How do I get this to mount as me as owner?

It's frustrating. Why is it really necessary to have root as the owner. Can't you just have a admin account that get that privilege?

As I have read, there are no way to set fat32/NTFS with owner. So there are no way I can change this. Atleast not that I am aware of.

I hope anyone one here can help me.

Update: It's labeled as vfat, not fat32. Not sure if that is the same thing.
Update 2: The screenshot show my language, but I do believe you know what it means. I will add mount shortly.

[image: Screenshot of the owner rights on my vfat external HDD]
`Mount` gives the output `vfat (rw)`

Comment: In Ubuntu, external HDD partitions mount as user readable and writable by default, not sure what's the source of your info. Also, 'root-permissions' are irrelevant in case of fat32. Add the output of `mount` to the question, that might help us help you. What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: I use ubuntu 12.04. I will add the output of mount later today. When I right click on my HDD and choose properties. And choose the tab Rights (I think it's called that in English, it's the second tab). The root is shown as owner. I will make a screenshot to.

Comment: mount your drive. It will show in /media/drivename. Now change the permission: sudo chmod -R 777 /media/drivename

Comment: I have tried to change owner with chmod earlier, but I gave it a try again. Root is still the owner. And when I try to change 777 to my username, I get "chmod: invalid mode" followed by my username. The strange thing is, when I use 777 I do not get invalid mode, but the owner is still root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it. I used the guide [mount guide](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/mountwindowsfstab)

Ok. Here is the steps I used.

1. Unmount drive. Used this command in terminal `sudo umount /media/your disk`.
2. I checked the partition table to see what path it was on with this command `sudo fdisk -l` in terminal.
3. I created a mount point `sudo mkdir /fat`. Just called it fat.
4. Then I created a backup of my fstab file using the command `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab_backup`.
5. Then I opened fstab with this command `sudo nano /etc/fstab`.
6. Then I added this to my vfat HDD `iocharset=utf8,umask=000 0 0`

And voila, when I mounted the HDD again I was the owner and not root :)`

The site I added also explains how to do this for NTFS HDD's too.

Comment: Please edit your answer to tell us specifically what you did to fix the problem--that's better than a web reference that might go away some day. Please leave the reference in your answer, though. Helpful sites deserve links (and credit).

Comment: Great! Thanks for documenting what worked for you.

Comment: user66987 you are a legend, many thanks this also solved my issue.